# How to do practical text-speak encoding

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I get textual entities that users have shortened from a smartphone, dumbphone or computer keyboard. This makes their searches for 'jstn' fail to retrieve 'Justin Roberts'. If they enter 'csr', 'caesar' must show up in auto-suggest.

In anticipation, I want to encode correctly spelled words into one or more possible 'text-speak' terms so that when users enter them we can retrieve, match and suggest the correct terms.

Here are just some kinds of variant spellings I have to account for:

```
justin -> jst, jstn, jtn
april -> apr, aprl
swedish -> swed swd
banglore -> blore
katrina -> kat
```

---

What are some good schemes to encode terms so that their text-speak and shortened words can also match them? I can think of:

Removing vowels : april ->aprl

Removing vowels and skipping some consonants : banglore -> bnglr, bglr

[Metaphone](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/how-tos/phonetic-hashing/index.html) which generates the same hash for similar-sounding words

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure it is a good approach to have a static database for this task. There are probably millions of possible "text-speak" terms, do you really think you can gather them all and keep your database up-to-date, when hundreds of new ones may be "invented" every week?

I would rather consider implementing that using a scoring system. First you need a list of "known words". This list can be limited to a couple of hundred words if you want to manage it by hand. On the other hand, it could also be huge, e.g. you could take all words from an English dictionary, including a couple of lists containing common first and last names, as well as common company and product names (e.g. a list of registered trademarks will cover most company and product names). Of course this is also a database that may need to be updated regularly but at least you only need to update the known words, not all "text-speak" terms. Note that on some systems there are build-in spellcheck dictionaries you may be able to use, which already give you a large base of known words.

Instead of also keeping tons of "text-speak" terms, you try to match whatever the user has entered to your list of known words following a set of rules:

1. All letters of the "text-speak" term must appear in the word.
2. All letters must appear in the same order as in the "text-speak" term.

These rules alone already eliminate plenty of impossible words. Now for the remaining words you need a way do determine how likely this is the word user meant. That's where the scoring system comes into play. You try to guess which word is more likely using some kind of heuristic.

E.g. all remaining words get a score of 0. For every two consecutive "text-speak" letters are also consecutive in the remaining words (no other letter in between that was left out), you increase the score by 2, since this makes the word much more likely. For every two consecutive "text-speak" letters that are not consecutive in the remaining word, but in between are only vowels that were left out, you increase the score by 1, since this still makes a hit more likely but not as likely as in the case before. And so on. You may also think of conditions that lead to negative scores, decreasing the score of words again. E.g. words get a negative score depending on the ratio between their length and the length of the "text-speak" term.

Such a heuristic never has perfect results but if you tune your scoring well, it can have pretty good results. E.g. `apr` matches `april`, but it also matches `aprilfool`, by the rules of above `april` wins, because it is shorter and closer to the length of `apr`. `jst` would match `just` but also `justin`. In that case `just` would win, which may be incorrect, but it may as well be correct, since I have seen `jst` for `just` plenty of times. Of course, `just` may make no sense in your case, so just don't add it to the list of known words. To get a good scoring system, one simply has to implement it and then start to fine tune it by adding or removing scoring rules and by changing the score added or subtracted in case  a rule matches. The more you play around with that, the better it will get.

Also keep in mind, that you can maybe ask the user, if in doubt. E.g. if a user types `jst`, you display a hit list with `Justin`, followed by `Justine` and the first hit on that list is always displayed as auto-suggest, but the user can also point on the second list entry to have that one completed. As a bonus, you can then make the scoring system a learning scoring system. If the user searched for `jst` ten times so far and each time he selected `Justine` from the list, never `Justin`, it looks like the user wants to rather search for `Justine` than for `Justin`. In that case you could maybe remember that choice and give `Justine` a couple of extra bonus points, so that it will always win over `Justin` in the future. Such a learning scoring system adopts to the user, since it will learn over the time what exactly a user means when he enters a specific "text-speak" term.

BTW, such as scoring system is how most SPAM filters on servers and in client software work. Including the "learning ability" if a user flags something as SPAM himself or unflags something that was erroneously marked as SPAM. In the beginning most SPAM filter systems are okay, not really good. If you keep using and such "training" them for longer time period, they get better and better and in the end, they will be right in 99% of all cases.